# XMPPError: service-unavailable - cancel

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Работаю со `Smack` и `xmpp`, при отправке файла с приложения получаю ошибку `XMPPError: service-unavailable - cancel`, что может быть не так?

```
 OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("test2@irynas-macbook-air.local/resource");
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/DCIM/Camera/test.jpg");
                try {
                    transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                    if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                        Log.e("ERROR!!! ", String.valueOf(transfer.getError()));
                    } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
                            || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
                        Log.e("Cancelled!!!",  String.valueOf(transfer.getError()));
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       Log.e("Error ", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }

   if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
                    Log.e("transfer refused", String.valueOf(transfer.getError()));
                }
                else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)){
//ошибка выпадает здесь
                        Log.e("transfer error", String.valueOf(transfer.getError()));
                    }
                    else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled))
                    {
                        Log.e("refused cancelled ",  String.valueOf(transfer.getError()));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Success","sending file");
                    }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поняла в чем ошибка, я указала неправильный id, в коде `test2@irynas-macbook-air.local/resource`, resource нужно было заменить на правильное название, в моем случае это было `Irynas-MacBook-Air`, то-есть, правильный `id` выглядит так: `test2@irynas-macbook-air.local/Irynas-MacBook-Air`